# Small instance and autoscale or big instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm about to get an Amazone ec2 account for my 4 e-commerce websites. Sometimes there is a big traffic or i have to make a lot of queries to generate some products feeds.
But there is something i can't figure out about this system : Why there is different instances specs ? 
I mean if i pay per hour, then why don't i get the smallest instance spec, and if needed the auto-scale will make 2 or 100 instances to deal with the traffic. 
So can someone advice or explain why should i or shouldn't do what i said above ? 
And why there is different instance sizes ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all applications are same, the number of requests these web applications handle quite different, basically Amazon AWS provides various flavors of virtual servers http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/, some are best suitable for E commerce websites with predictable bursts, blogs with less usage, Compute intensive apps, Media Streaming Servers which requires higher RAM etc.

You decide the best suitable type and size of the virtual server for your application to begin with and then scale up and scale down based on the load. AWS provides reference use-cases and best practices here http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/ to architect elastic, scalable and fault tolerant web services.